# Best way to manage database schema creation using nest js?

Tags: node.js, database, nestjs

On previous personal projects I have manage everything related to database schema changes through sql files containing the changes (one file to create the database, other to seed it, other scripts to do updates) and then running the content of the files on the database directly.

Now I am starting a new project and I have doubts about if it is a good idea to continue using this sql files approach and simply make the databases entities in nest mirror the sql database.

I am not sure if this one is a good approach or there are better or simpler ways.

Comment: Check `Prisma`. It covers all of your needs.